# Uploading Parsing a text file with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, parsing

so I'm trying to upload then parse a text file with the following format:

> Mar 29 19:23:51,667|DEBUG|1    |1: Initializing lorem ipsum... 
>   Mar 29 19:23:31,682|ERROR|1    |1: Lorem.Ipsum.Exception while starting Foo.Bar.Launcher 
>   System.Blah.LoremException: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... 
>       at System.Lorem.Ipsum.Dolor.foo() 
>       at System.Lorem.Ipsum.Dolor.foo() 
>   ... 
>   Mar 30 22:23:23,667|DEBUG|1    |1: Initializing lorem ipsum... 
>   Apr 02 17:24:17,413|ERROR|4    |4: Lorem failed to ipsum... System.DolorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       at Lorem.Ipsum.Dolor.IpsumDbController..ctor()

And the Error class:

```
public class Error
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ErrorType { get; set; }
}
```

## Where There are Two Errors:

### Error 1

**Mar 29 19:23:33** - is the Date
**System.Blah.LoremException** - is the ErrorType. 
**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit** - is the Description

### Error 2

**Apr 02 17:24:17** - is the Date
**System.DolorException** - is the ErrorType. 
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** - is the Description

Is there an easy way I can parse the string (through regex? or not?)? I was thinking of splitting the string if it contains ERROR, then getting the next line to assign to ErrorType.

I'm not quite sure how I would go with this, so any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE :** The pattern is really inconsistent, so I'm not really confident with the String.Split solution.

The general rule is:

All |ERROR| will have a Date **(our string Date)**, System.blah.LoremException **(our ErrorType)** followed by an Exception message **(our Description)**

The ErrorType & Description could possibly be inline with the ERROR string or on the next line.

Comment: Have you got anywhere so far? I do something similar and I used string.split in order to separate the info from my file.

Comment: Not yet, not in my dev PC. I'll try tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of a StreamReader and Regular Expressions to handle parsing.

```
    private static List<Error> ParseErrors(string filepath)
    {
        Regex parser = new Regex(@"^(?<date>\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2}){2}),[^\|]+\|ERROR\|[^:]+\s*(?<description>.+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        string line = string.Empty;
        Match curMatch = null;
        var errorLog = new List<Error>();

        using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(filepath))
        {
            while (!sReader.EndOfStream && (line = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                curMatch = parser.Match(line);
                if (curMatch.Success)
                {
                    errorLog.Add(new Error()
                    {
                        ID = errorLog.Count, /* not sure how you assign ids? */
                        Date = curMatch.Groups["date"].Value.Trim(),
                        Description = curMatch.Groups["description"].Value.Trim(),
                        ErrorType = sReader.ReadLine().Trim()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return errorLog;
    }
```

The logic behind this is basically to iterate through the stream line-by-line searching for a match to the regular expression. The regular expression itself is tailored to fit only "ERROR" lines, so it won't match on "DEBUG" etc.

If the line matches the expression, a new "Error" class instance is put into the list, and the parsed values from the Regular Expression are used to populate the fields. To fill the "ErrorType" field, I simply read the next line following the match.

### EDIT

Okay, the best way I can see is by matching the trailing "..." at the end of the error messages when the exception is on the same line, then attempting to match further.

Revised code:

```
    private static List<Error> ParseErrors(string filepath)
    {
        Regex parser = new Regex(@"^(?<date>\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2}){2}),[^\|]+\|ERROR\|[^:]+:\s*(?<description>.+?)(?:\.\.\.\s*(?<type>.+))?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        string line = string.Empty;
        Match curMatch = null;
        var errorLog = new List<Error>();

        using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(filepath))
        {
            while (!sReader.EndOfStream && (line = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                curMatch = parser.Match(line);
                if (curMatch.Success)
                {
                    errorLog.Add(new Error()
                    {
                        ID = errorLog.Count, /* not sure how you assign ids? */
                        Date = curMatch.Groups["date"].Value.Trim(),
                        Description = curMatch.Groups["description"].Value.Trim(),
                        ErrorType = (curMatch.Groups["type"].Success ? curMatch.Groups["type"].Value : sReader.ReadLine().Trim())
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return errorLog;
    }
```

Comment: Looks solid! Will try it out tomorrow!

Comment: Without a large sample to look at the Regex may be a bit patchy. If it doesn't work in some cases let me know and I'll tweak it.

Comment: Makes it quite a lot more difficult to make a reasonable pattern as now a lot of the parsing would be `best-guess`. You could look for System\. in the string to find where the exception starts but that means you wont be able to capture custom exceptions. Is there any way you can modify how you log the errors and come up with a more standardised loggin pattern?

Comment: Sadly no, I don't control the logs :( I just accept and parse them.

Comment: Alright edited my answer. It's still pretty much a "best guess".

Comment: Neat, definitely a better solution than mine. But the logs really vary that there is no consistent pattern. I was told to get only predefined exceptions (no custom exceptions) but yeah, if this is a logging tool, it should capture all type of exceptions. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as you are thinking. Split each line on the `|`, check to see if the 2nd element equals `ERROR` and, if so, assume I need to handle that line and the next.

Comment: Thanks! Will wait for other answers though! I'm really anticipating someone with godlike regex skillz will come by. Plus, I can't code it right now.

Comment: You could certainly do it with RegEx, but I'm not sure what you would gain. RegEx's tend to be a big, slow hammer. I wouldn't go there unless I had to.

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like that in a loop... You could also use split as I mentioned before, just that like that could be a bit more effective

```
if (line.Contains("ERROR"))
                {
                    data = true;
                    continue;
                }


                if (data)
                    //here you deal with the following line
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved it, it's not the most elegant solution though, so if you have other answers, please feel free to post them here.

```
    public static List<Error> ParseErrors(string filepath)
    {
        //separated the two regex
        Regex dateRegex = new Regex(@"^\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Regex errorRegex = new Regex(@"((?<type>System.*?Exception):\s(?<description>.*\.))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        string CurrentLine = string.Empty;
        string NextLine = string.Empty;

        List<Error> errorLog = new List<Error>();

        using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(filepath))
        {
            while (!sReader.EndOfStream && (CurrentLine = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if (CurrentLine.Contains("|ERROR|"))
                {

                    Match DateMatch = dateRegex.Match(CurrentLine);
                    Match ErrorMatch = errorRegex.Match(CurrentLine);

                    string date = DateMatch.Groups[0].Value.Trim();
                    string errorType = string.Empty;
                    string description = string.Empty;

                    //Check if error type and description is residing in the current line, otherwise, check at the next line
                    if (!ErrorMatch.Groups["type"].Value.Equals("") && !ErrorMatch.Groups["description"].Value.Equals(""))
                    {
                        errorType = ErrorMatch.Groups["type"].Value.Trim();
                        description = ErrorMatch.Groups["description"].Value.Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NextLine = sReader.ReadLine();
                        ErrorMatch = errorRegex.Match(NextLine);
                        errorType = ErrorMatch.Groups["type"].Value.Trim();
                        description = ErrorMatch.Groups["description"].Value.Trim();
                    }

                    Error NewError = new Error();
                    NewError.Date = date;
                    NewError.ErrorType = errorType;
                    NewError.Description = description;

                    //a bit lazy with the regex, just take the first sentence of the description if it has multiple sentences.
                    if (NewError.Description.Contains(". "))
                        NewError.Description = NewError.Description.Substring(0, NewError.Description.IndexOf(". "));

                    // Do not add if it's a custom exception.
                    if(!NewError.Description.Equals("") && !NewError.Description.Equals(""))
                        errorLog.Add(NewError);
                }
            }
        }

        return errorLog;

    }
```